# Is this a reasonable workload?

Tags: print-design, book

this might not be the place to ask this question, but I don't know anyone else in my field.

I work for a book publisher. I design around 90% of their 100+ books per year. I have worked there for 7 years, since I got out of college. In addition to designing covers (minimum 3 comps each), set them up for print, and troubleshoot any preflight problems, I interface with authors, do the quarterly catalog (of 100+ projects), and maintain administrative work.

Lately, this work has been added to with a number of drop-in projects (4 in the last month, including a kid's book to paginate).

So...

1. Is this is considered a regular workload?
2. Am I paid enough? $22/hr.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This *might* fit at http://workplace.stackexchange.com but it really doesn't fit here. There is no such thing as a "normal" workload. People tend to rise to the level of their incompetence.

Comment: Telling tour hourly sallary isnt as useful as you think. Its relative to the locale you are in. Certainly here that would be ok. But anyway you can always renegotiate or change jobs.

Comment: The question of wages is always a touchy one, and there are so many factors that go into it.  Where are you living / working.  A "normal" wage for Manhattan would be completely different from the boonies of the midwest.  Are you the only person in your department? Do you answer to a supervisor? Everyone is replaceable, just not always easily replaced, where do you fall on that scale?  What hours do you work per day / week. a re you hourly or salary? what are your benefits? soo many more questions.

Comment: Basically, if you think you're being paid enough, great, if not, then you need to have a talk with your employer.